Burai shows Gold conventional as ibarv 1 SC
When loading the cif file for a conventional cell of Au with 4 atoms, burai shows it as ibrav 1 (SC), but Au is FCC which would be ibrav 2. When loading the cif for a primitive cell of Au it does show the correct group.
Can someone elaborate why is this. Thanks in advance

Isn't this simply due to the fact that you can represent an fcc lattice as a sc lattice with a 4-atom basis? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/789778/49107

Then how would one define the brillouin zone path in that case. SC would have the symmetry points gG–X–M–gG–R–X|M–R. While FCC has gG–X–W–K–gG–L–U–W–L–K|U–X. Using the FCC path with ibrav 1 results in error for letter W.
Can you simply use the SC path with the 4 atoms cif file?

Burai had it's last update 6 years ago (2018), and it remains quite unfinished and unpolished. QE version at the time was 6.4. Now it's 7.3, and a lot has changed since, including input file options. I vaguely recall a change specifically affecting the cell definition. At this point, I would recommend againist using BURAI in general.

Thanks @Neinstein.
